# Python - Print(df) Only Showing First Row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am a beginner to python. This seems like something that would have been asked but I have been trying to search for the answer for 3 days at this point and can't find it.

I created a dataframe using pd after running pytesseract on an image. Everything is fine except one 'minor' thing. When I want it to show the dataframe, if the first series is 'Date', it shows only the first row:

```
df['Date'] = pd.Series(date_date)
df['In'] = pd.Series(float_in)
df['Out'] = pd.Series(float_out)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].fillna(date_date)
df['Out'] = df['Out'].fillna(0)
df['In'] = df['In'].fillna(0)


print(df)

  Date   In     Out
0 2022-05-31  0.0  7700.0
```

If I change the column sequence and keep column 'Date' on any other position, it comes out fine:

```
df['In'] = pd.Series(float_in)
df['Out'] = pd.Series(float_out)
df['Date'] = pd.Series(date_date)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].fillna(date_date)
df['Out'] = df['Out'].fillna(0)
df['In'] = df['In'].fillna(0)


print(df)

   In       Out       Date
0  0.0    7700.0 2022-05-31
1  0.0    4232.0 2022-05-31
2  0.0   16056.0 2022-05-31
3  0.0   80000.0 2022-05-31
4  0.0   40000.0 2022-05-31
5  0.0  105805.0 2022-05-31
6  0.0  185500.0 2022-05-31
7  0.0   52188.0 2022-05-31
```

Can anyone guide as to why this is happening and how to fix it? I would like the Date to remain the first column but of course I want all rows!

Thank you in advance.

Here is the complete code if that helps:

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd=r'C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe'

img = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\Fast Computer\\Documents\\Python test\\Images\\page-0.png")
thresh = 255

#Coordinates and ROI for Amount Out
x3,y3,w3,h3 = 577, 495, 172, 815
ROI_3 = img[y3:y3+h3,x3:x3+w3]

#Coordinates and ROI for Amount In
x4,y4,w4,h4 = 754, 495, 175, 815
ROI_4 = img[y4:y4+h4,x4:x4+w4]

#Coordinates and ROI for Date
x5,y5,w5,h5 = 833, 174, 80, 22
ROI_5 = img[y5:y5+h5,x5:x5+w5]


#OCR and convert to strings
text_amount_out = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI_3)
text_amount_in = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI_4)
text_date = pytesseract.image_to_string(ROI_5)

text_amount_out = text_amount_out.replace(',', '')
text_amount_in = text_amount_in.replace(',', '')

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#Convert Strings to Lists
list_amount_out = text_amount_out.split()
list_amount_in = text_amount_in.split()
list_date = text_date.split()

float_out = []
for item in list_amount_out:
    float_out.append(float(item))

float_in = []
for item in list_amount_in:
    float_in.append(float(item))
    
date_date = datetime.strptime(text_date, '%d/%m/%Y ')


#Creating columns
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['In'] = pd.Series(float_in)
df['Out'] = pd.Series(float_out)
df['Date'] = pd.Series(date_date)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].fillna(date_date)
df['Out'] = df['Out'].fillna(0)
df['In'] = df['In'].fillna(0)


print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies with how you initialize and then update the `pd.DataFrame()`.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

float_in = [0.0,0.5,1.0]
float_out = [0.0,0.5,1.0,1.5]

# this line just gives you 1 value:
date_date = datetime.strptime('01/01/2022 ', '%d/%m/%Y ')
# date_date = datetime.strptime(text_date, '%d/%m/%Y ')

# creates an empty df
df = pd.DataFrame()

print(df.shape)
# (0, 0)
```

Now, when you first fill the df only with a series that contains `date_date`, we get:

```
df['Date'] = pd.Series(date_date) # 1 row

print(df.shape)
# (1, 1)

print(df)
#         Date
# 0 2022-01-01
```

Adding any other (longer) `pd.Series()` to this, will not add rows to the df. Rather, it will only add the *first* value of that series:

```
df['In'] = pd.Series(float_in)

print(df)
#         Date   In
# 0 2022-01-01  0.0
```

One way to avoid this, is by initializing your df with an index that stretches the length of your longest list:

```
max_length = max(map(len, [float_in, float_out])) # 4

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(max_length))

print(df.shape)
# (4, 0), so now we start with 4 rows

df['Date'] = pd.Series(date_date)

print(df)
#         Date
# 0 2022-01-01
# 1        NaT
# 2        NaT
# 3        NaT

df['In'] = pd.Series(float_in)
df['Out'] = pd.Series(float_out)

df['Date'] = df['Date'].fillna(date_date)
df['Out'] = df['Out'].fillna(0)
df['In'] = df['In'].fillna(0)

print(df)

        Date   In  Out
0 2022-01-01  0.0  0.0
1 2022-01-01  0.5  0.5
2 2022-01-01  1.0  1.0
3 2022-01-01  0.0  1.5
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use iterable with repeated date rather than single date, consider following simple example

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = pd.Series(datetime.date(1900,1,1))
df['Values'] = pd.Series([1.5,2.5,3.5])
print(df)
```

gives output

```
         Date  Values
0  1900-01-01     1.5
```

whilst

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Date'] = pd.Series([datetime.date(1900,1,1)]*3)  # repeat 3 times
df['Values'] = pd.Series([1.5,2.5,3.5])
print(df)
```

gives output

```
         Date  Values
0  1900-01-01     1.5
1  1900-01-01     2.5
2  1900-01-01     3.5
```

Comment: Thanks. Can it figure out how many times it needs to repeat based on how many values there are in the other columns?